# Bayesian estimation of log-normal using JAGS

Tags: bayesian, confidence-interval, jags

I try to find 95% credible interval of 50 sample means. Sample sizes range from 2 to 600, and the values in each sample are bounded between 1 and 5.
ex:

```
sample 1 = (1,3.5,2.8,5,4.6)
sample 2 = (1,5)
sample 3 = (4.1,1.1,5,3.5,2,2.4,...)
```

Samples with size of 10 or more have a lognormal distribution where i used JAGS for Bayesian estimation of log-normal parameters adapted from John K. Kruschke, with model specification as below:

```
 modelstring = "
  model {
    for( i in 1 : N ) {
      y[i] ~ dlnorm( muOfLogY , 1/sigmaOfLogY^2 )
    }
  sigmaOfLogY ~ dunif( 0.001*sdOfLogY , 1000*sdOfLogY )
  muOfLogY ~ dunif( 0.001*meanOfLogY , 1000*meanOfLogY )
  muOfY <- exp(muOfLogY+sigmaOfLogY^2/2)
  modeOfY <- exp(muOfLogY-sigmaOfLogY^2)
  sigmaOfY <- sqrt(exp(2*muOfLogY+sigmaOfLogY^2)*(exp(sigmaOfLogY^2)-1))
}
"
```

The model works fine with sample size > 10. However, with 3 <= samples < 10 i got  extreme values in upper limit (e.g., 3000) which exceeded the maximum possible value of the mean (e.g., 5).
In case of sample size = 2, i got the below error:

```
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'
```

I am new to JAGS and can't figure out how to solve this issues. I think for smaples < 10  the distribution is no longer lognormal!
Any ideas?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First a semantic note. You are not using JAGS to find sample means. You are using JAGS to find the means of the populations from which the samples arose.  If you wanted to find the sample (log)means, you could just take the mean of the (logarithms of the) sample values.

Now, if the values in each sample are bounded between 1 and 5 (due to some external constraint), then the sample is NEVER drawn from a log-normal distribution, which inherently puts probability mass over values greater than five.

Let's imagine, for the sake of saying, that the samples do arise from lognormal sampling (and therefore aren't inherently bounded between 1 and 5).  Then JAGS is simply telling you that there is not enough information contained in the sample to get a good estimate of the population mean from which it is drawn. I wouldn't worry about understanding the error when the sample size is two, because there is literally no way to get good inference about the population mean from two samples.  This is true even if you know that the population is indeed log-normally distributed.  And since your populations are not actually log-normally distributed (they are bounded between 1 and 5) the entire inferential procedure is invalid anyway.